# Stacking boxes without exceeding specific height in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 box types, each box have different height, for example:

```
Box A: heightA = 2.50
Box B: heightB = 2.95
```

It's required to stack boxes of type A and B over each other, such that the total height of stacked boxes doesn't exceed 30, but nearest to 30.

How to solve this problem in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not required C#, you can implement this "Math question" in any language.
There are multiple ways to handle it. One "manual" way is that i can think of is:

Let number of box A = a
Let number of box B = b
We have: 2.5a + 2.95b <= 30

Since we need

> stack boxes of type A and B over each other

We will have `| a - b | = { 0; 1}`

Meaning we have 3 cases:

1) `a - b = 0` => `a = b`

In this case we will have `2.5a + 2.95a <= 30` => `a = 30 div 5.45`
So we have box A = 5 box B = 5

2) `a - b = 1` => `a = b + 1`

In this case we have  `2.5(b+1) + 2.95b <= 30` => `2.5b + 2.95b <= 30- 2.5` => get b => get a

3) `b - a = 1` => `b = a + 1`

Similar like case 2) get a and b, then compare 3 cases.

Well at the end, you don't even need coding language

***EDIT***

If max height is a key in number, then it should be more like programming code required.

In this case, but like i said because this line make the logic so simple:

> stack boxes of type A and B over each other

you just need to compare 3 cases , and get the value you want

Comment: @Jacky Thank you for the good answer, and for thinking outside the box, actually i didn't want code or specific language, i wanted some idea outside the box. Please ignore negative comments, keep up the good posts.

Comment: @NetSolver, if you didn't want code the simple solution would have been to not ask for a solution in a specific language. Title: "Stacking boxes without exceeding specific height in C#". Question: "How to solve this problem in C#?" I'm failing to see what you're having an issue with. I'll be glad to remove my downvote on this answer *and* the question if you make it reflect what you claim to be asking - it's simple.

Answer (score 1):

Well Mathematically, you can Find:

Total Box A's that can be stacked = 30 / 2.50 = 12 (Height reached = 30)

Total Box B's that can be Stacked = 30 / 2.95 = 10 (Height reached = 29.5)

Now there can be several ways to stack.

Ex 1: Take only 1 Box A and all other Box B's
i.e. 30 - 2.5 => 27.5 / 2.95 => 9 Box B's + 1 Box A

So, your code must do Permutation. (Spoiler !!)

Comment: I've edited the question, it should be nearest to 30.

Answer (score 0):

While you can solve this with brute force rather quickly, a generic way of solving this sort problem is mixed integer linear programming.

```
 Maximize:   2.5 A + 2.95 B

 Subject To: 
             2.5 A + 2.95 B <= 30
             A >= 0, Integer
             B >= 0, Integer
```

You can use Google OR Tools to do this with C#: https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cs